# Matrix representation in C

Tags: c, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I want to find out what is the best representation of a m x n real matrix in C programming language.

What are advantages of matrix representation as a single pointer:

```
double* A;
```

With this representation you could allocate memory:

```
A = (double* )malloc(m * n * sizeof(double));
```

In such representation matrix access requires an extra multiplication:

```
aij = A[i * m + j];
```

What are disadvantages  of matrix representation as a double pointer:

```
double** B;
```

Memory allocation requires a loop:

```
double** B = (double **) malloc(m * sizeof(double*));
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    A[i] = (double *) malloc(n * sizeof(double))
```

In such representation you could use intuitive double indexing `bij = B[i][j], but is there some drawback that would affect performance. I would want to know what is the best presentation in terms of performance.

These matrices should be used in numerical algorithms such as singular value decomposition. I need to define a function:

```
void svd(Matrix A, Matrix U, Matrix Sigma, Matrix V);
```

and I am looking for the best way to represent Matrix. If there is any other efficient way to represent a matrix in C, please, let me know.

I have seen that most people use single pointer representation. I would like to know if there are some performance benefits as opposed to double array representation?

Comment: You are missing example code that accesses specific number in matrix and allocates the matrix itself thus it is impossible to tell what matrix representation you did mean. (It was not me who did downvote though.)

Comment: Can you please tell me if this is any better or should I just delete the question?

Comment: In the second case you can reduce number of mallocs to 2 or even 1. I.e. you can malloc one big `double *` chunk (with same length as in first variant) and assign `A[0]=malloc_result`, `A[1]=malloc_result+n`, `A[2]=malloc_result+2*n` and so on (assuming type of `malloc_result` is `double *`). With one malloc you allocate `sizeof(double *)*m + sizeof(double)*n*m` and assign `A=malloc_result`, `A[0]=(double *)(malloc_result+m)`, `A[1]=A[0]+n`, `A[2]=A[1]+n` and so on (assuming type of `malloc_result` is `(double **)`). There is no need in doing m+1 allocations.

Comment: Though these variants have a downside of `valgrind` not being able to detect out-of-bounds array access: since `A[0][n]` is simply `A[1][0]` trying to assign to it is not an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the memory accesses required.

For the single-pointer case, you have:

1. read a pointer (the base address), probably from a register
2. read the four integers, probably from registers or hard-coded into instruction set.  For `array[i*m+j]`, the 4 values are `i`, `m`, `j` and `sizeof(array[0])`.
3. multiply and add
4. access the memory address

For the double-pointer case, you have:

1. read a pointer (the base address), probably from a register
2. read an index, probably from a register
3. multiply the index by the size of a pointer and add.
4. fetch the base address from memory (unlikely to be a register, might be in cache with luck).
5. read another index, probably from a register
6. multiply by the size of the object and add
7. access the memory address

The fact that you have to access two memory locations probably makes the double-pointer solution quite a bit slower than the single-pointer solution.  Clearly, caching will be critical; that's one reason why it is important to access arrays so that the accesses are cache-friendly (so you access adjacent memory locations as often as possible).

You can nit-pick about details in my outline, and some 'multiplication' operations may be shift operations, etc, but the general concept remains: the double-pointer requires two memory accesses versus one for the single-pointer solution, and that will be slower.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of articles about row major format.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order

http://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/row-major-vs-column-major-and-gl-es/

These are common constructs in CUDA programming; hence my interest.